# Regex - Extract email address from a string in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, parsing

I want to parse out email addresses from a string in PowerShell.

For example, given:

```
$email = "take this email test@mail.com"
$email2 = "secondmail@mail.com"
$email3 = "thirdmail@mail.com needs extracted"
```

I would get:

```
test@mail.com
secondmail@mail.com
thirdmail@mail.com
```

The domain is the same among all these strings, it will always be an username@mail.com address.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Regex in Powershell to grab email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564679/using-regex-in-powershell-to-grab-email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to extract email for your particular domain name.

```
\w+@mail.com
```

As long as username part in your email only contains alphabet, numbers and underscores. Else instead of \w you may have to write character class like this,

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@mail.com
```

Like you can see this contains alphabets, numbers, undrscore, dot, hyphen

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by this answer

[How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

and this answer

[Powershell: Extract text from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113231/powershell-extract-text-from-a-string)

this would help ....

```
$email = "take this email test@mail.com"
$email2 = "secondmail@mail.com"
$email3 = "thirdmail@mail.com needs extracted"
$email4 = "fourthmail@mail.com and fifthmail@mail.com and sixthmail@mail.com"

$email_regex = "(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|`"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*`")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])"

$extracted = [regex]::match($email, $email_regex).Value
$extracted

$extracted = [regex]::match($email2, $email_regex).Value
$extracted

$extracted = [regex]::match($email3, $email_regex).Value
$extracted

[regex]::matches($email4, $email_regex)|select value
```

the last line shows how to extract more email occurences from one text

Comment: Becareful. You're including a " symbol in your regex causing the quotes to break. Using a back tick ` symbol should alleviate that issue

Comment: yes, i have there back tick, because i'm careful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
$email = "take this email test@mail.com"
$email2 = "secondmail@mail.com"
$email3 = "thirdmail@mail.com needs extracted"

$array = @($email,$email2,$email3)

foreach($a in $array){

    $split = $a.Split(" ")
    $email = ($split | ? {$_ -match "@"})

    $email
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple in PS;

```
# initialize your string and pattern (you can choose your own pattern)
$message = "I'm a creep.1990_radio@gmail.com, I'm a wierdo_head@gmail.com"
$pattern = "([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})"

# get all the matches and store it in an array
$results = ($message | Select-String $pattern -AllMatches).Matches

# iterate over array to act on those items
foreach ($item in ($results)) { Write-Host $item.Value }
```

In last line, you could also use `Write-Host $item` to see available attributes.